# Java project with Visual Studio Code on raspberry pi (Java Language Server icon keeps spinning)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I'm new to Raspian as well as the Raspberry Pi and just got a Raspberry Pi 400. I would like to use it to work on some small Java projects. To do this, I would like to use Visual Studio Code as an IDE. However, once I create a new Java project in VS Code, the icon in the bottom right hand corner indicating the "Java Server Status" simply keeps spinning, so that I cannot actually run the main method.
I roughly followed the directions given [here](https://vimeo.com/418199389) by

- Installing VS Code using `sudo apt install code`
- Installing Maven using `sudo apt install maven`
- Installing the "Extension Pack for Java" in VS Code
- Creating a new Maven project in VS Code (using maven-archetype-quickstart with version 1.4).

I then encounter the problem mentioned above and cannot even run the "Hello World" demo.
When I run `mvn -v`, I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Raspian, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.63-v7l+", arch: "arm", family: "unix"
```

while `java -version` returns:

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7.post-Raspian-2deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.12+7.post.Raspian-2deb10u1, mixed mode)
```

I also tried to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable as described [here](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-raspberry-pi/) and to manually add `java.home` as well as `JAVA_HOME` to the "settings.json" file found in `/home/pi/.config/Code/User`, but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial/JavaHelloWorld.Standalone.mp4), can you get right output?

Comment: Could you find a solution on that?